# CSS : wondering what does "\" mean in CSS

Tags: css

I'm trying to make dropdown menu with tailwindCSS

and there is a good example for me :
https://codepen.io/PILO7980/pen/EBVxPE

but i can't recognize where is a hover control, and what is \ mean in CSS.

hope kindly help me.

```
.group:hover .group-hover\:block {
  display: block !important;
}
```

Comment: There is no :block [pseudo element](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp). So it is a pure escape character.

Comment: from the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6732899/8620333

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\` has no specific CSS meaning aside of escaping the next character. Here it allows to include the `:` as part of the `group-hover:block` class name and avoids interpreting it as a pseudo-selector (all of which are starting with the `:` character).

Regarding the hover control, it is actually implemented through the inline styles of your linked example. For instance `<a class="font-semibold whitespace-no-wrap text-blue-600 hover:text-blue-800"` means "apply the `font-semibold`, `whitespace-no-wrap` and `text-blue-600` CSS classes on this anchor, and apply the `text-blue-800` class on it when it is hovered".

Answer (score 0):

Since the `:` character is used in the class name (group-hover:block) you need to escape it in the CSS file with the `\` character so basically the `\` in `.group-hover\:block` is just to escape the special character of :